# Safe way to access List index

Tags: dart

I'm newbee to Dart.

I have troubles to find an easy to read way to "safely" access a List element at any index

```
final List<String> myList = <String>[]
myList.add("something")
// ...
String myGetter(int index) {
  // "heavy" way
  if (index < myList.length) {
    return myList[index]
  }

  return null;
}
```

If I go with regular `[index]` or `elementAt(index)` and index is out of boundaries, it throws a `RandeError`

Is there a method that returns null when the index cannot be reached?

> Sorry if double posted, but I try to find the info without any success, + not sure if there is an (un)official slack / discord to ask this kind of "easy" questions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dart lists do not allow invalid indices. There is no built-in way to get a `null` when trying. Not in the platform libraries.

You can create your own helper function (like you already do):

```
T? tryGet<T>(List<T> list, int index) => 
    index < 0 || index >= list.length ? null : list[index];
```

(Remember to check for negative indices too).

As suggested, you can also add it as an extension method:

```
extension ListGetExtension<T> on List<T> {
  T? tryGet(int index) =>
    index < 0 || index >= this.length ? null : this[index];
}
```

which may make it more pleasant to work with.

(I recommend against doing something bad and then catching the error, at least when you can easily check up-front whether it's bad or not).

Answer (score 4):

You can defined an [extension method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) to catch the `RangeError` and return `null`:

```
void main() {
  print([1, 2].get(3)); // display null
}

extension SafeLookup<E> on List<E> {
  E get(int index) {
    try {
      return this[index];
    } on RangeError {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the return type must be E? in order to be able to return null

Answer (score 4):

Presently you can use `elementAtOrNull` for a list,

```dart
YourList.elementAtOrNull(5)
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.1/dart-collection/IterableExtensions/elementAtOrNull.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
void main() {

  List<int> teste = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  print(teste.get(1));
}

extension ListExtension<E> on List<E> {
  dynamic get(int value) {
    return this.contains(value) ? value : null; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/List-class.html):

> throws a RangeError if index is out of bounds.

So you can use the [try-catch block](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#ch02-exceptions-catch):

```
String myGetter(int index) {
   try {
      return myList[index]; 
   } 
   on RangeError {
  // Called when the index is out of bounds
      return null; 
   }
}
```

If you want to be extra cautious I guess you could put a generic `catch` at the end (to catch all kinds of throws that are not RangeError), but in a simple getter like this I think that would not be necessary:

```
[...]
 }catch (e) {
  // No specified type, handles all other types of error/exceptions
      return null;   
   }
[...]
```